# Ajax Form and checkboxes array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, checkbox

In my ajax form i have some checkboxes and a textbox for email address. The form work, but i can't send the checkboxes array and email address in the same variable. Sorry for my bad english. Here's jquery code :

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$('#submit').click(function () {

var valore = { 'how_hear[]' : []}; 

$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
  valore['how_hear[]'].push($(this).val());
}); // Checkboxes value

var name = $('input:text');
```

// Organization of data to send to php. I think the problem is here, but i can't solve!!!

```
var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&check=' valori;

$.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'myurl.php',
                data:  data, // If i send only the variable "name" or only the variable "valore", it works fine!
                cache: false,
                success:function (data) {
                    $('form').append('GIUSTO!!!!');
                }
        });

    return false;
    });

});
```

Any suggestion? Thank u!

Comment: use `$(yourForm).serialize()` and add attribute `name="how_hear[]"` on your checkbox elements in order to create your `data` variable which is sent to server. [Link to .serialize() official doc](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) or [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method.

Answer (score 0):

**Sending Data to the Server**

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

By default, Ajax requests are sent using the GET HTTP method. If the POST method is required, the method can be specified by setting a value for the type option. This option affects how the contents of the data option are sent to the server. POST data will always be transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset, per the W3C XMLHTTPRequest standard.

*`The data option can contain either a query string of the form key1=value1&key2=value2, or a map of the form {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}`*. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent. This processing can be circumvented by setting processData to false. The processing might be undesirable if you wish to send an XML object to the server; in this case, change the contentType option from application/x-www-form-urlencoded to a more appropriate MIME type.